# How to find frequency of each element in DatagridView

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview, datatable, element

I have a DataGridView which looks a little like this:

```
ColumnName
hello
hello
bye
hello
bye
crocodile
hello
crocodile
```

How do I find the count of each element? i.e Hello = 4, bye = 3 and crocodile = 2
Seeing as they're outputted in a DataGridView column.

Please help

Comment: Have you considered looping through the column and counting them?

Comment: If you really have a DataTable, you could query it.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to query the `DataGridView` but looping and creating groups with `Linq` also works. So this is my idea to do it:

```
Sub CountRows()

    Dim lstCountRows as List(Of String)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In MyDataGridView.Rows
        '2 is the index of the column you are querying
        lstCountRows.Add(row.Cells(2).Value)
    Next
    'Create groups for the values on lstCountRows 
    Dim groups = lstCountRows.GroupBy(Function(value) value)
    'Loop and print the groups count
    For Each group In groups
        MsgBox(group(0) & "-" & group.Count)
    Next

End Sub
```

Give it a try and let me know your comments